# How to create html option tag with different styled words in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, dropdown

I want a select box with options having one word on the left extreme and the second word on the right extreme.

E.g.

```
<select>
  <option>Suzuki Car</option>
  <option>Volvo Bus</option>
</select>
```

In the above example "suzuki" should float left and the "Car" should float right.
Also I want the "Suzuki" to be bold but not the car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it because `<option>` tag can not have child elements. Please, **[read documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):**

> **Content categories:**   None.
>
> **Permitted content:**    Text, possibly with escaped characters.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting you a sample ***psuedocode*** --

There must be a way in this style if you are using **jQuery**:

```
for each <option> in <select>{
   split(<option-value>)[0].css('text-align', 'left');
   split(<option-value>)[1].css('text-align', 'right');
}
```